Confusion about inverse kinematics of simple double-jointed arm
I hope this doesn't come across as too much of a check-my-work. If not, please let me know of a better site for this, or I'd appreciate being moved. I'll get straight to the point.
I'm trying to produce 2D inverse kinematics for a double-jointed arm modeled like so:

Here's the Desmos page so you can try moving the point around and seeing why the behavior clearly isn't correct: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dkv8vyhbl2
Forward kinematics yields the following:
$$
x = L_1\cos a + L_2\cos(a + b) \\
y = L_1\sin a + L_2\sin(a + b)
$$
Squaring both expressions (sparing you that algebra), and combining them to solve for $\cos b$:
$$
\cos b = \frac {x^2 + y^2 - L_1^2 - L_2^2} {2L_1L_2} \\
\sin b = \sqrt {1 - \cos^2 b} \\
b = \arctan2 (\sin b, \cos b)
$$
From the original forward kinematics:
$$
x = (L_1 + L_2\cos b)\cos a - L_2\sin b \sin a \\
y = L_2\sin b \cos a + (L_1 + L_2\cos b)\sin a \\
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}(L_1 + L_2\cos b) & -L_2\sin b \\ L_2\sin b & (L_1 + L_2\cos b)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos a \\ \sin a\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos a \\ \sin a\end{pmatrix} = \frac 1 {L_1^2 + L_2^2 + 2L_1L_2\cos b} \begin{pmatrix}(L_1 + L_2\cos b) & L_2\sin b \\ -L_2\sin b & (L_1 + L_2\cos b)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
a = \arctan2 (\sin a, \cos a)
$$
With these two angles solved for in terms of the desired final point and lengths of the joints, I would expect the arm on Desmos to actually behave well. Clearly, I've done something wrong along the way, and I can't figure out what it could be. I'm fairly sure I've implemented the way the lines are rendered as functions of their angles, and I got the "atan2" implementation from somewhere else, but it seems to work fine. I hope it isn't something wrong I've done on Desmos. That would be embarrassing.
Once again, I apologize if this isn't the right site for this, I'm not sure of myself.

I think there is a sign error in the matrix: the off-diagonal terms should be reversed to get the right expressions. In addition, with your choice for $\sin b$ you are constrained to $0\le b\le\pi$: is that true? Finally, denominator in the inverse matrix should have $2L_1L_2\cos b$.

Oops, those switched signs and the missing $2$ are typos in transcribing my work. I'll fix that. I wasn't aware of the restriction caused by $\sin b$. How could I try to address this? Ideally I want the full range of $[-\pi, \pi]$ for both angles

@Intelligentipauca But even so shouldn't the restriction of $b$ to $[0, \pi]$ have no actual effect on the angles necessary to reach the target point? The alternative would be to choose $-\sqrt {1 - \cos^2 b}$ but this also behaves just as strangely

False alarm. It was just as I feared. The silly mistake was made on Desmos itself, and I couldn't see it no matter how much I stared at my math. I'd written $(L_1 + L_2)y\cos b$ rather than the correct $(L_1 + L_2\cos b)y$.
Sorry about that. It works now. If you'd like to play with it, here's the fixed version.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nxhjf55hdf
